# New Data Connection Issue

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to write in Server name text box  visual studio close the add connection screen without an error message.
This happens in new data connection wizard.

I have already tried  reseting and  deleting files.
Visual studio version 2015

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. You need to provide more information if you want to get a good answer.

Comment: I am trying to add a NEW Connection with SQL Server from toolbox with the wizard.